# Is a video frame an independent image?

Tags: video, frame

If a video file claims it has 30fps and 10 seconds, can it extract exactly 300 images?

Does every type of video file consist collection of images?

Answer (score 5):

That will be true only if you have an uncompressed video.

Videos normally use compression so they update the part of the screen that changed, and not the whole screen, everytime (this depends on the codec and the type of compression).

You can check more about this here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_coding_format